# Can reputation scoring system be implemented using business rule management system (BRMS), such as OpenL Tablets, in PHP?

Tags: php

Can reputation scoring system be implemented using business rule management system (BRMS), such as OpenL Tablets, in PHP? From reputation scoring system I mean the reputation systems as in StackOverflow.

I recently come across [Business Rules Management Systems (BRMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rule_management_system)). [OpenL Tablets](http://openl-tablets.sourceforge.net/features) looks promising, though at the onset it seems to be created with the use in insurance sector in mind.

I looked at SO and found this [Best Open Source Business Rule Management System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707933/best-open-source-business-rule-management-system) but it does not answer the question.

Another post Is [using Rule Engine to implement chain of rules [complex business logic] overkill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541707/is-using-rule-engine-to-implement-chain-of-rules-complex-business-logic-overki)? but still couldn't figure out.

There are bunch of different product suggestions here but still doesn't answer if it will be worth the effort [PHP Business Rule Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069887/php-business-rule-engine)

I will highly appreciate your answer.

Note: This is a yes/no question, and not an open ended question. Please give it a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding OpenL Tablets

1) It is a general-purpose business rules management system, though you are right in the sense, that many customers happen to be in the insurance sector :)

2) It is a pure java application, so you will have to call it from your PHP module, there could be a performance overhead because of JVM startup cost. There is an option of deploying OpenL Tablets as a web service and calling the service, this approach will have better performance

3) Yes, you can implement scoring system using OpenL tablets. You can use decision tables, lookup tables and calculation spreadsheets to develop a fast calculation engine, i do recommend to give it a try and post your feedback.

Overflow reputation system looks like a simple table-driven calculation. The algorithm should just run all stored events for a particular user through these tables and accumulate the score.

Comment: would you mind sharing your experience about openL tablets? it will be helpful in understanding the contexts. thanks.

Comment: are you aware of any literature/book that discusses how to use OpenL Tablets to implement reputations scoring mechanism as that of StackOverflow? thanks again.